# como puedo instanciar objetos dentro de un área en unity3d

Tags: c#, lista, unity3d

el area es referencianda por una lista de puntos, como la de la imagen.
puede variar en la cantidad de puntos.
la lista de puntos ya esta creada, incluso genero un mesh, triangulando los puntos instanciados en cada click.

pero me pregunto como puedo instanciar objetos dentro de esa area.

se me ocurrio instanciar objetos dentro de un trigger (que seria adjuntando un collider al mesh creado) pero no funciono, o quizas lo hice mal.

alguna idea?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Agrega lo que probaste para que otros puedan ayudarte con eso. Sobre todo, si pensas que lo hiciste mal, tal vez alguien lo pueda corregir

Answer (score 0):

Tu teoría de generar un collider al mesh es buena... Para hacerlo se me ocurre que generes el mesh, obtengas valores de sus bounds y generes una posición random entre estos límites, una vez tengas la posición valides por la forma si la posición generada está dentro del collider del mesh con Physics.CheckSphere, no estoy seguro de que funcione pero creo sería un buen aproach:

```
public void GeneraElementoEnRandomPos(){

  Mesh planeMesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
  Bounds bounds = planeMesh.bounds;//Obtenemos medidas del mesh

  float minX = gameObject.transform.position.x - gameObject.transform.localScale.x * bounds.size.x * 0.5f;
  float minZ = gameObject.transform.position.z - gameObject.transform.localScale.z * bounds.size.z * 0.5f;

  Vector3 newVec = new Vector3(Random.Range (minX, -minX),
                             gameObject.transform.position.y,
                             Random.Range (minZ, -minZ));//Posición random dentro de los límites
  while(!Physics.CheckSphere(newVec,.0001){//Si no hay collider envolviendo al objeto volvemos a generar posición random dentro de los límites
    newVec = new Vector3(Random.Range (minX, -minX),
                             gameObject.transform.position.y,
                             Random.Range (minZ, -minZ));
  }
  Instantiate(prefab, newVec, Quaternion.identity);//Instanciamos ya en una posición válida...
}
```